# How to delete data from database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When I select rows from DataGridView the data will show up on Textbox. But by the time I click Delete Button this shows up

[image]

Error message:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'First Name='Jesus Anthony''.

It appears that there's a missing operator. What does it mean? My TextBox is not empty. Here is the code I used

```vb
provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
datafile = "C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\Registration Form\Database\EmployeeRegistration.accdb"
connString = provider & datafile
myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
myConnection.Open()
Dim str As String
str = "DELETE FROM tblemployees WHERE First Name='" & Form1.firstname.Text & "'"
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

Try
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
    myConnection.Close()
    clearall()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: "Datas" isn't a word.  It's just "data."  If you want the singular, it's "datum."

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: @djv Actually... It was being inserted to the database which the DataGridView can automatically retrieve the data once I click the Add Button. Now I'm really having problems with Updating

Answer (score 2):

`First Name` has a space in it.  If that's really the field name, you have to surround it with brackets, like this:

```
[First Name]
```

Otherwise, it's just `FirstName`